# Spring 3.1.1 Placeholder failure in WebSphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websphere-8

I have a spring application deployed to a WebSphere 8.5.5 installation that has an issue where it occassionally starts up and fails to load the property file subsitutions.  After a few restarts, it will pick up the place holder values and properly start up.  When it fails to pick up the values, it results in a stack trace error similar the snippet I'll be adding to the bottom of this post.

We've contacted IBM Support, but they believe it to be a Spring Framework Placeholder Configurer issue after their investigation of our collected logs.  I've also attached a snippet of our bean configuration for reference.  Is this a known issue in Spring?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

STACK TRACE ERROR:

```
[9/29/16 9:28:57:197 CDT] 000000e0 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
[9/29/16 9:28:57:199 CDT] 000000e0 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[apiWeb]: org.springframework.beans.fa
ctory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'mailSender' defined in class path resource [spring-mailsender.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder '
mailsender.host' in string value "${mailsender.host}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:174)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:662)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1709)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1178)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1383)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:972)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:174)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:662)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1709)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1178)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1383)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
```

BEAN DEFINITION:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="location">

        <!-- This factory bean will provide a classpath resource pointing to 
            environment/[env].properties, e.g. environment/dev.properties. 
            It will get the name of the environment from the Java system
            property runtime.environment. -->
        <bean class="com.czr.ocrm.integration.util.EnvPropertiesResourceFactory">
            <property name="systemPropertyName" value="runtime.environment"/>
            <property name="propertiesFilePrefix" value="environment/"/>
            <property name="defaultEnvironment" value="dev"/>
            <property name="propertiesFileSuffix" value=".properties"/>
        </bean>

    </property>

    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>

    <!-- This setting means any properties set using Java system properties will
        override what is in the properties file. -->
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>

    <!-- Lowest priority so the containing app can override -->
    <property name="order" value="9999"></property> 
</bean>
```

Comment: add mailsender.host=mailsender-host-endpoint to dev.properties.

Comment: from the stacktrace you can see that it is unable to resolve the placeholder ${mailsender.host} from the properties file. In simple words, this property along its value is not defined in the dev.properties file

Comment: If you look at the stack trace you see it isn't related to your configured `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` but a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. You are only posting a snippet but I suspect you have a `<context:placeholder-configurer />` in your xml configuring another bean. So I doubt it is a spring or web sphere issue but a matter of wrong/too much configuration.

Comment: <context:placeholder-configurer /> wasn't anywhere in my xml configuration.  I don't receive this error outside of when I deploy to WAS 8.5.5.

Comment: @NeilOcampo  Did you get the solution for this. 
I'm also using `<bean id="myBean"   class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
 <property name="location" value="classpath:myProperties.properties" />
 <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>`.I'm accessing properties in file by @Value("{propertyname}") annotation in java class. This work well in liberty server in local and IT env, but when I deploy it to websphere in higher environment, No property is loaded. For sure its a websphere issue. as this works in liberty